# How to tell Supervisor that there's no need to stop a program?

Tags: supervisord, mojolicious, hypnotoad

Perl Mojo Hypnotoad server has a hot restart feature. To update a program you only need to start Hypnotoad again and it eventually will replace all running copies.

How to tell Supervisor that there is no need to stop my server while restarting it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know correct answer, but i want to try to answer...

The restart of supervisord takes place in two stages:

1. stop
2. start

So, according to [mojo docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Hypnotoad#QUIT) and [supervisord docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) (see to `stopsignal`) you need to do something like this:

```
stopsignal=QUIT
stopwaitsecs=20000  # big number, it very depend from your project, because don't know how much time need to close all exsisting connections
```

Optionaly you may to add this options:

```
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```